# How to pass parameters to a class extending view in android from activity class

Tags: java, android, android-layout, view, android-xml

I have a class which extends Activity.

I also have a layout for that activity which includes a `videoview` and `progressbar`.

There is another class which extends View and creates rectangles on top of the progress bar in the activity layout.

I want both the main layout and the rectangles created by view class to be visible in the same screen.

I need to pass parameters to the view class to set the positions of the rectangle.

As far as I know, you cannot set 2 content types from an activity class.

So I ended up calling the view class from my layout like this:

```
  <com.example.user.CanvasHeat
    android:id="@+id/viewCanvas"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

But, this way I cannot pass parameters to the `CanvasHeat` class.

And if I create the `CanvasHeat` class from the Activity Class then I cannot set the main layout and the rectangles simultaneously.

**How should I display both the layout and the rectangles in the same screen and also pass parameters to the view class?**

Thanks

Comment: `"There is another class which extends View and creates rectangles on top of the progress bar"` why? what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

The only way I see is to declare some methods in your view class to set properties after it was inflated in Activity. Like this:

```
class CanvasHeat extends View {
    public void setValue(int value){ ... }
}
```

Then in your Activity:

```
View viewCanvas = findViewById(R.id.viewCanvas);
viewCanvas.setValue(42);
```